# JSON-P and a GET resource?

Tags: javascript

If a website operating on a domain other than my own supports get requests, like:

```
http://api.someothersite.com/v1/farms
```

There's no way for me to access it using JSON-P right, they would have to have support for it as a query parameter? Something like:

```
http://api.someothersite.com/v1/farms?callback=fantastic
```

I mean, there's no way for me to use it without them explicitly supporting it, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct.  For JSONP to work, the server must choose to process and echo a callback parameter.